# Using embedded database with Flyway and jOOQ in Maven for continuous integration

Tags: maven, hsqldb, travis-ci, flyway, jooq

So I'm really trying to do things 'right' with [SQL that will break at compile time using flyway and jOOQ](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/06/25/flyway-and-jooq-for-unbeatable-sql-development-productivity/). To do this I need a database solution that can work on the [continuous integration server](http://travis-ci.org) with no access to any server-based database. Ultimately, I want to deploy this to Amazon so I need a solution that is [mostly compatible with postgreSQL](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_compatibility_postgres). [HSQLDB's file protocol](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCConnection.html) seems to fit that bill.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<properties>
    <schema></schema>
    <db.groupId>org.hsqldb</db.groupId>
    <db.artifactId>hsqldb</db.artifactId>
    <db.version>2.3.2</db.version>
    <flyway.url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:myDB/db</flyway.url>
    <flyway.driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</flyway.driver>
    <jooq.generator.database.name>org.jooq.util.hsqldb.HSQLDBDatabase</jooq.generator.database.name>
    <flyway.user></flyway.user>
    <flyway.password></flyway.password>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${db.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${db.artifactId}</artifactId>
        <version>${db.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>migrate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <locations>
                    <location>filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration</location>
                </locations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>

            <!-- Specify the maven code generator plugin -->
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>

            <!-- The plugin should hook into the generate goal -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <!-- Work around Maven's classloader -->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${db.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${db.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <version>${db.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <configuration>

                <!-- JDBC connection parameters -->
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>${flyway.driver}</driver>
                    <url>${flyway.url}</url>
                    <user>${flyway.user}</user>
                    <password>${flyway.password}</password>
                </jdbc>

                <!-- Generator parameters -->
                <generator>
                    <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
                    <database>
                        <name>${jooq.generator.database.name}</name>
                        <includes>.*</includes>
                        <excludes></excludes>
                        <inputSchema>${schema}</inputSchema>
                    </database>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>package.goes.here</packageName>
                        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                    </target>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The problem is that Flyway can create the database fine, but when it becomes jOOQ's turn to use the database to generate code, it fails with:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@1096ec89[file =...db/db.lck, exists=true, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: checkHeartbeat read: 2015-02-09 03:56:15 heartbeat - read: -863 ms.
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile.newLockFileLock(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.acquireLock(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
```

The core of problem is that [Maven's plugins do not share the same classloader as the rest of the POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-classloading.html), and you must specify the JDBC driver dependency a second time. Thus I get a new instance of the driver and it conflicts with the already open driver Flyway has open, instead of using the same one.

So a solution may exist along a number of different paths:

1. Flyway could close the database properly.  Apparently Flyway has a workaround in its plugin to read the project's classpath.
2. jOOQ could be configured somehow to read the project's classpath.
3. There might be another database that would work better.
4. Yours!

Comment: bit lame: Spawn separate JVM for some of the Maven tasks.

Comment: The same issue happened recently to another user using Derby embedded: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4007

Comment: For the record, if you weren't using Flyway, [here's another way to solve this problem with the `sql-maven-plugin`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33123477/521799)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Thilo for the direction.  Replacing the Flyway plugin with exec works, but I had to [create a simpler command line client](https://github.com/AveryRegier/flyway-simple/tree/master) to make it work.